# Memory leaks doubts in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have tested my application with leak instrument.There is only one leak in my application.It came from a array declaration.But i didn't know how to solve this.This is my array code.These three code is leaked.Please do help me.

```
allSelectedVerseEnglish = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    allSelectedVerseMalayalam = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    allSelectedVerseHindi = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just release the arrays when u don't need them anymore, say in **dealloc** method

```
[allSelectedVerseEnglish release];
[allSelectedVerseMalayalam release];
[allSelectedVerseHindi release];
```

or else you could simple use **convenience constructors** as below, (you dont have to release)

```
allSelectedVerseHindi = [NSMutableArray array];
allSelectedVerseMalayalam = [NSMutableArray array];
allSelectedVerseHindi = [NSMutableArray array];
```